# Website does not render properly in IE9 / Comino and iPad / iPhone browsers - sidebar drops to the bottom, below content

Tags: css, wordpress, html, themes, internet-explorer-9

I have a website that is running on latest (as of now) WordPress, and heavily modified "journalist" theme.

Web site here: http://www.roofingcalculator.org/

Here is the problem - In IE 9, Comino and iPad / iPhone browsers, sidebar drops below content and comments on ALL pages

It works correctly in IE 8 (though it shows various security / page errors crap) Chrome, Firefox, Safari on both PC and Mac, most Android browsers, etc.

My CSS is structured so that content flows left, and sidebar flows left.

I tried adjusting the width of content, thinking that IE9 sees it as wider (together with sidebar) than the whole page design, which is 993 px wide.

I was not so worried about it on iPhone / iPad, as those are minor, but IE9 is 25% of my total traffic, and that needs to be fixed.

Please help. Thank you all.

PS - I read multiple posts on this, but did not find the solution - I'm thinking it is because I customized the theme ... but I use same theme on multiple sites, and it is a big problem if it does not render correctly.

Comment: Your website is not available, can you give the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing the errors in the table code and the missing or out of place `<div>` tags. Code errors are a big cause of layout problems in WP themes, esp. sidebars that drop down.

[[Invalid] Markup Validation of   roofingcalculator.org  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.roofingcalculator.org/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.